# How to add a constraint for multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I added a constraint to a table so that the users cannot insert duplicate records for `employee_nbr`.

```
ALTER TABLE GamePresenterDB.gp.player_objects
    ADD CONSTRAINT AK_UniqueName UNIQUE (employee_nbr);
```

This works fine, but I realize now that an employee number is associated with a `group_id`. So, the table can have duplicate `employee_nbr` column values as long as it is associated with a different `group_id` column.

How do I add a constraint so that the user is unable to enter a duplicate `employee_nbr` for the same `group_id`?  My primary key in the table is a different identity column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the combination of `group_id` and `employee_nbr` unique:

```
ALTER TABLE GamePresenterDB.gp.player_objects
ADD CONSTRAINT AK_UniqueName UNIQUE (group_id, employee_nbr);
```

(and of course, drop the old constraint)

Comment: perfecto.  Thanks a bunch...